# React - Updating State's Component From Another File

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Suppose that I had a React component such as

```
    import { getEventListener } from 'controls';
    class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
          render() {
             return (<div onClick={this.handleEvent}></div>) 
          }

          handleEvent = (event) => {
             getEventListener(event, this);
          }
    }
```

And I have another file such as

```
   export function getEventListeners(event, component) {
       component.setState({x: 1};
   }
```

If getEventListeners calls set state from the component to change one of the properties would it cause an issue?

Comment: What exactly does getEventListeners do? Please, list it.

Comment: Semantically it makes no sense to change the state of component somewhere else since the state of a component is it's locally scoped state nothing else should interfere with. What are you trying to achieve exactly? There is most likely a better approach you implement your desired behavior.

Comment: @ChristianIvicevic well, my component has become bulky, and I just wanted to move some functionality to another file and I thought I make a file that handles all the event listeners

Comment: If its another file, use the function keyword and return something to the parent. I havent tried, but sounds doable. Just worried if it throws some error at setState

Comment: In your code it doesn't use `event`. A function that uses a parameter and a function that doesn't can be treated differently.

Comment: @a2441918 It actually doesn't throw an error nor does it mess up performance. I was just wondering if someone else has tried this and has encountered an error in the long run.

Comment: Then you have a reusable function...

Comment: I think you may need to use render props pattern so you can reuse your logic. Take a look at this link https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html. It may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This causes the design issue, passing the whole component by reference and accessing it in a function breaks [the principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). Calling the function with a context like `getEventListener.call(this, event)` would have the same problem.

If `getEventListener` isn't supposed to be reused between components, it shouldn't be extracted from a component where it's used. It uses `this.setState` method and clearly belongs to a class. In case multiple inheritance is involved, a mix-in can be used.

A solution that is idiomatic to React is reusable [state updater function](http://getEventListener). It's decoupled from a component and supposed to be used for pure synchronous functions:

```
   export const getEventListeners = event => state => {
     // return state object that derives from an event
   };

   ...

   this.setState(getEventListeners(event));
```